# Multi-Browser Compatible Fixed Width Code

Tags: html, css, fixed-width

I am seeking code advice for how to create a fixed width layout that is compatible with multiple browser sites. I have looked at several other questions posted on this site, but none have completely helped me with my specific coding issues. I would appreciate any suggestions or tips to make the code more functional.

The link for the site homepage is hooknhornsranch.com

The code that I have been working with is here:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hook-N-Horns Ranch, LLC</title>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: auto;
/* Preserve aspet ratio */
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
right: auto;
z-index: auto;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
overflow: scroll;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
}

.outer{
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:solid blue 1px;
}

.top, .middle, .bottom{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: solid red 1px;
top: 424px;
left: 14px;
position: absolute;
}

.bottom{
border:solid orange 1px;
}

.middle{
border:solid green 1px;
}

.inside-middle{
text-align:right;
display:block;
}

#menu{
height: 3px;
width: 615px;
padding-top: 67px;
padding-left: 495px;
top: -10px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
}

#photo{
height: 300px;
width: 685px;
top: 90px;
left: 266px;
border: 12px solid #FFF;
}

#banner{
height: 225px;
width: 481px;
background-image: url(images/bannerslice.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top: -2px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
}

#welcomeimage{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 366px;
height: 225px;
left: 285px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
}

#welcometext{
height: 166px;
width: 283px;
left: 650px;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: -60px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #12060A;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
font-family: ".tk-museo";
}

#footer{
height: 67px;
width: 754px;
top: 662px;
left: 249px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
}

.tk-museo-slab {
font-family: "museo slab";
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: left;
}

.tk-museo {
font-family: museo;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: left;
}

 a:link {
color: #190C0B;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #190C0B;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.muesoslab500white {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tk-museo {
font-family: ".tk-museo-slab-12p";
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/brv6oja.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="bottom" id="container">
    <div class="top" id="menu"><span class="tk-museo-slab"><span class="museoslab500"><a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/ekscott22/Documents/Hook N Horns Web/about.html">About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> <a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/ekscott22/Documents/Hook N Horns Web/cattle.html">Cattle&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>  <a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/ekscott22/Documents/Hook N Horns Web/wheat.html">Wheat&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>  <a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/ekscott22/Documents/Hook N Horns Web/hunting.html">Hunting &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> <a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/ekscott22/Documents/Hook N Horns Web/management.html">Management </a></span></span></div>

<div class="bottom" id="photo"><img src="images/homepagecattle1.JPG" width="685" height="300" alt="cattle" /></div>

<div class="middle" id="banner">
</div>

<div class="middle" id="welcomeimage"><img src="images/welcomeimageslice.png" width="356" height="213" alt="Welcome to Hook-N-Horns Ranch" />
</div>

<div class="middle" id="welcometext"> <span class="tk-museo">In 2010, Hook-N-Horns Ranch, LLC was created as a small scale cattle and crop raising ranch. Today HNH manages over 1,000 acres of land with over 100 head of cattle.<br /><br />
HNH is proud to raise premium Black Angus beef, excellent crops of winter wheat as well as a maintaining healthy wildlife populations for large and small game hunting. Please explore our site to learn more about Hook-N-Horns Ranch. </span></div>
<img src="images/bigbackground.png" width="1280" height="800" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like for the content to be centered in the window and compatible with other browser dimensions. When the page is opened all the content should be visible and centered within the browser window. It looks this way on my computer but is not the case when tested on other computers. I would really appreciate any guidance that anyone can offer!

Comment: Why not start with a framework such as http://960.gs/ or http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/